# No clutch pressure in N15 Pulsar (GA16DE)

Tags: nissan, clutch, pedals, clutch-cable

I have a Nissan Pulsar 1998 N15 and the clutch has been playing up last few days.

When I press the clutch in, it would not come all the way back up. Would only come back up about 2/3 of the way and would get "stuck" before going back all the way up.

Then this morning I put the clutch in, the clutch "gave way" and lost all pressure. Sounded almost like a snapping noise but I think it was just my clutch/foot hitting the floor.

At first I thought it could be low on brake/clutch fluid but as I was trying to find the clutch reservoir I find out the clutch is cable oriented.

Has anyone else had this issue and know how I should go about diagnosing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Clutch cable I'm looking to get

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you broke the clutch cable from your description.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I see, do you have any recommendations on how I could go about confirming this before buying a replacement?

Comment: Pull the cable from the transmission side ... if it comes out, there's an issue.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 So I just gave this a go and the cable is happy to come out when pulled on the transmission end. I assume this indicates a snapped clutch cable and is the issue to my problem. You should make that an answer and I will mark it a the correct answer

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 One last question, do you think its fine to get a second hand clutch cable from a wrecker over a new one?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a now snapped cable. The snapping noise was probably the last few steands of the Bowden cable breaking.

Given the cost of a new one and the possibility of a second hand one not lasting long, I would go for new.

You will most likely have to replace the inber and outer together due to the ends in the Bowden cable.

Smaller cables are easier to buy a length and solder the ends on - used to do that a lot.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise there are two parts to the cables, would I have to buy two of these cables?

Comment: Sorry the cable in my edit in the post

Comment: @VehicularIT a new cable comes as a complete unit as you show.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the clutch cable snapped.

To test this, pull the cable from the transmission side ... if it comes out, there's your issue.

If money is tight, you have to do what you have to do. There's nothing inherently wrong with getting a 2nd hand clutch cable. If you go this route, before you actually purchase it, test it. Do this by moving the cable within the sheath back and forth. If it moves freely without any noise/binding, it should be okay. When I say "noise/binding", if you hear any clicking inside the tube, there's most likely damage and the cable has started to fray. There will be some resistance even when good, but it should still feel like it's sliding freely.